# Symfony2 and HHVM Declaration of Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection::prepare() must be compatible

Tags: symfony, hhvm

i am trying to set up a symfony2 project on a HHVM machine,

The HHVM is running on FastCGI as explained in the hhvm tutorial, thus running behind an apache2 server on Debian.

I have created everything but when i try to run my application i am getting the following error:

```
ContextErrorException: 16777217: Declaration of Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection::prepare() must be compatible with that of Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\Connection::prepare() in /LOCATION/shared/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php line 30
```

I am thinking this has something to do with PDO in HHVM but i tested it using the class_exists('PDO') and that says that PDO is enabled

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an issue that was fixed via a pull request to the master branch of doctrine/dbal about 2 months ago. However, depending on the branch of Symfony 2 you are using, that doctrine/dbal fix may not be included.

https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/pull/373

If it is possible to use a version of Symfony 2 that includes this latest doctrine/dbal fix, I think you will see that issue go away.

Comment: i am using the 2.4 branch

Comment: So Symfony's 2.4 branch has a composer.json which gets the 2.4.x-dev 1770ffa version of doctrine/dbal. doctrine/dbal 2.4.x-dev does not have the fix referenced by the pull request above. So if you change the Symfony 2.4 composer.json to explicitly get the master branch of dbal/doctrine, that should hopefully help you.

Comment: Doing this resolves the issue, however, it seems to break the authentication system, though it is not clear why. After upgrading my dbal deps, I am no longer able to register or login, though this works  fine under PHP 5.5 (my app only uses 5.4 code).

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same issue and upgrading doctrine/orm and doctrine/dbal to latest versions (listed below) fixed my problems.

doctrine/orm : 2.5.*@dev 
doctrine/dbal: 2.5.*@dev

To safely upgrade, open your `composer.json` file, find and change the versions like so:

composer.json

```
"require": {
    // ... other package requirements
    "doctrine/orm": "~2.5.*@dev",
    "doctrine/dbal: "~2.5.*@dev", 
    // .. more packages
```

Then run `composer update doctrine/*` which will remove the old versions of doctrine and update all doctrine packages.

Comment: It is great that you have mentioned `composer update doctrine/*` (especially the asterix in the end). I didn't know about this feature and was always having troubles when I had to update only certain dependencies... This helps a lot.

Comment: However as of now there's stable versions of `doctrine/doctrine-bundle 1.3.*` there's stable `doctrine/dbal 2.5.*` and today's latest stable  `doctrine/orm 2.4.6` as it's dependency constraint on `doctrine/dbal` specified `~2.4`. Which means that it accepts today's latest `2.5` as well. Which means that in typical symfony2 project we only need to specify `"doctrine/orm" : "~2.4.6"` and `"doctrine/doctrine-bundle" : "~1.3.0"`. And there's no need to explicitly set `doctrine/dbal` neither adding `@dev` to depend on unstable versions. :) HTH

Answer (score 1):

The declaration of

```
Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection::query()
```

must be compatible with

```
PDO::query(string $query, ?int $fetchMode = null, mixed ...$fetchModeArgs)
```

I had the same problem, but the solution was to just change the PHP version from version 8 to 7.3.

- Login to your Cpanel with your credentials, search for MultiPHP Manager.
- Select the domain or subdomain that you would like to change the PHP version of.
- Select from the dropdown menu and chose the appropriate PHP version. (For me, 7.3 worked like a charm.)

Everything worked like it supposed to.